# How do vocations other than Knights even live?

Tags: tibia

Supposedly, Sorcerers, Druids, and Paladins are meant to fight at a distance; and while mages are allowed a crappy shield forever, Paladins are supposed to ditch spear+shield combo and permamently switch to bows and crossbows after level 150.

However, *Tibia* is the most claustrophobic MMO I've ever known:

- the game's window 15x11 grid is a pretty small one,
- a lot of caves and hunting rooms are tight,
- monsters have a tendency to dogpile you right after up/down stairs/hole/ladder,
- and it seems that as of version 13.20, you can no longer push monsters around like in 2012.

Taking that into account, I have absolutely no idea how to play non-Knights the way they are intended.

So - how does one go about playing a distance character in *Tibia*?

Comment: Kiting, mana shield, and health/mana potions. Invisibility depending on the monster.